# how to get lat long from google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How to get latitude and longitude from below function.

```
<script>        
    getPlace_dynamic();  
    function getPlace_dynamic() {
        var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631)
        );
        var input = document.getElementsByClassName('formcontrol');
        var options = {
            bounds: defaultBounds,
            types: ['establishment']
        };
        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i], options);
        }

    }
</script>
```

**I want to get lat and long from above function in below line**

```
 document.getElementById('tolat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById('tolong').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to get place information from autocomplete?

[Autocomplete for Addresses and Search Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#get_place_information):

> "When a user selects a place from the predictions attached to the
>   autocomplete text field, the service fires a place_changed event. You
>   can call getPlace() on the Autocomplete object, to retrieve a
>   PlaceResult object".

So your code could look like this

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = this.getPlace();
    document.getElementById('tolat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('tolong').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
    ...
```